# Is it possible to allocate a segment using the Windows API?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, x86

I am wondering if it is possible for a Windows program to allocate a segment descriptor within the process' local descriptor table. Is there a Windows API function that can install a new segment descriptor to the running process' LDT using a provided linear offset, segment length, and combination of flags (RWX)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible using undocumented NT API, specifically NtSetLdtEntries.
Note that Windows x86-64 does not set up an LDT so this only works on x86.

[Here's](http://vxheavens.com/lib/vzo13.html) some code.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am curious about your claim that "x86-64 has no LDT". Reading the Intel Architecture manuals, there is no indication that x86-64 does away with the LDT. In fact, there is the sentence "The local descriptor table register (LDTR) and the
task register (TR) also expand to hold a full 64-bit base address." Do you mean that 64-bit Windows does not use the LDT?

Comment: Yes, I meant that Windows x64 doesn't set up an LDT. http://www.reactos.org/pipermail/ros-dev/2006-August/008775.html